React router dom v6.26.1 changes url but not re-render the component
I'm having an issue with the page refresh after, when clicking on the button url gets changed in the browser but the page doesn't refresh the correct component, no browser error no terminal error, everything is good at the code level.
please find the sandbox link
error in sandbox -> 
<BrowserRouter>
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/login-otp" element={<LoginOtp />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
    </Routes>
  </Suspense>
</BrowserRouter>

Below is the Redux-saga method call where exactly I'm trying to push the URL on OTP page after API success as I say URL is changing but OTP page does not re-render the UI.


import axios from 'axios';
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
function* submitEmail(action: any) {
    try {
        const payload = {
            username: 'emilys',
            password: 'emilyspass',
            expiresInMins: 30,
        };
        const http: [string, object] = [`https://dummyjson.com/auth/login`, payload];
        const { data: res } = yield call(axios.post, ...http);
        if (res?.token) {
            yield put(push('/login-otp'));
        } else {
            console.log("res:: ", res)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error:: ", e)
    }
}



this is how I set up Redux config


import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { createInjectorsEnhancer } from 'redux-injectors';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();

const staticReducers = {
  router: connectRouter(history),
}

function createReducer(asyncReducers?: any) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...staticReducers,
    ...asyncReducers
  })
}


export default function configureStore() {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod' &&
      typeof window === 'object' &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__<any>({
        shouldHotReload: false,
      })
      : compose;

  const injectEnhancer = createInjectorsEnhancer({
    createReducer,
    runSaga,
  })

  const store: any = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(
        sagaMiddleware,
        routerMiddleware(history)
      ),
      injectEnhancer
    )
  );

  store.asyncReducers = {};

  return store;
};



index.tsx file


import configureStore from './path';
const store = configureStore();
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
    );
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
              <App />
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );



yield put(push('/login-otp'));  --> this make the route update but not update UI.

Why are you using Suspense there? What is being lazy loaded?

@Asplund , Issue which I'm facing is exactly like this, https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/304

Didn't find the proper solution to this issue.

I see no issue in the code you have shared here, so perhaps the issue is elsewhere. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with that produces the problem. See also if you can create a running CodeSandbox demo that we could inspect live.

@DrewReese , i have added more detail about exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for reply

Uh, so you are trying to use some Redux actions to effect navigation changes in the BrowserRouter? Can you [edit] to include a full/complete [mcve] of your router and redux setup so we can see how they are possibly connected? FWIW react-router-redux hasn't been updated in like 8 years and wasn't even the common/useful way to connect RRD and Redux 5 years ago, and React-Router v6 certainly broke the way most of those older libraries worked with Redux.

@DrewReese I shared the Redux config, please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Issue
React-Router-Redux is very old and deprecated, their repo points you to Connected-React-Router, and it's not even compatible with the last previous React-Router-DOM version.

Project Deprecated
This project is no longer maintained. For your Redux <-> Router
syncing needs with React Router 4+, please see one of these libraries
instead:

connected-react-router

⚠️ This repo is for react-router-redux 4.x, which is only compatible
with react-router 2.x and 3.x

Unfortunately at this point in time Connected-React-Router is also a dead project and hasn't been updated to be compatible with React-Router-Dom v6.
Solution Suggestion
The current/modern replacement library for connecting RRDv6 to Redux is Redux-First-History.
You are also using old/outdated Redux code. Modern Redux is written using Redux-Toolkit. It's highly recommended to update to RTK.
Here's an example modern refactor/implementation:

Create a Redux store with router reducer & middleware integrated (I think this captures all/most of your old implementation):
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createReduxHistoryContext } from "redux-first-history";
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { createInjectorsEnhancer } from 'redux-injectors';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const {
  createReduxHistory,
  routerMiddleware,
  routerReducer
} = createReduxHistoryContext({ history: createBrowserHistory() });

const staticReducers = {
  // ... other root-level reducers ...
  router: routerReducer,
}

const createReducer = (asyncReducers?: any) => combineReducers({
  ...staticReducers,
  ...asyncReducers
});

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;

const injectEnhancer = createInjectorsEnhancer({
  createReducer,
  runSaga,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createReducer(),
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(routerMiddleware, sagaMiddleware),
  enhancers: getDefaultEnhancers =>
    getDefaultEnhancers().concat(injectEnhancer),
});

store.asyncReducers = {};

export const history = createReduxHistory(store);


Import the store and history object and instantiate and wrap your app in a HistoryRouter:
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';
import { history, store } from './path';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

App.tsx - remove the router since it is rendered higher in the ReactTree now:
<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/login-otp" element={<LoginOtp />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
  </Routes>
</Suspense>




, <Router history={history}> this wrapper throwing error _ Type 'History & { listenObject: boolean; }' is missing the following properties from type 'History': createURL, encodeLocationts(2739)
index.d.ts(82, 5): The expected type comes from property 'history' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HistoryRouterProps' _

@sudo_code Ah, do you know what version of history is installed? Are you using history@5, the current/latest version? Do you happen to have any "@types/...." for react-route-domand/orhistory` also still installed for some reason? The latest versions are written in Typescript so there's no need for the additional 3rd-party typings.

,  Yes, i have installed the latest version of "history": "^5.3.0", and i have also installed the "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",  some other types installed.

@sudo_code Since you are using React-Router-DOM@6 you'll need to remove the types for the older v5 version, RRDv6 is already typed on its own.

i have uninstalled the @types/react-router-dom but still issue persist.

@sudo_code I see. If it's not too much trouble do you think you could create a running CodeSandbox demo that we could inspect live? I'll try the same.

@sudo_code In your sandbox, I don't see any issue with the history prop passed to the history router. I also don't see any issue clicking the "log in" button and navigating to "/login-otp" route and rendering the LoginOtp component. The only issue I see is that App is still rendering an extraneous BrowserRouter, you should remove this. Does this fork run well for you?

i have removed the BrowserRouter  and now in sandbox, it's working ok, but if you see the error in index.tsx file for  <Router history={history}><App /> it's showing same error that i facing in my local environment. and in browser page shows error. and not loading.

@sudo_code I don't see any error/issue in the index.tsx file. Do you see the same error in the forked sandbox I linked? Maybe restart your TS server in your IDE?

,  i have attached the error image, have a look once. same issue in my local also, even after restarting IDE. in sandbox it working with an error but in my local, it's breaking with the same error.

@sudo_code Ah, you know RRDv6 has been a little frustrating to work with over its lifetime, and I think this is another of those "breaking changes" scenarios as they move towards RRDv7/Remix-Run v3. All the RRDv6 routes are Remix routers under-the-hood, and it looks like they have duplicated the History interface inside the code there, separate from their history module. Using import { History } from "@remix-run/router"; and casting history (history={history as unknown as History}) seems to work. I've updated the sandbox fork.

, I'm not able to any changes, same issue.  Could you please reshare the link here?

@sudo_code Here? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-heisenberg-mg6sw8

,  Fantastic!!! it works! Thank you for supporting. You made my day.

@sudo_code Ah, great! Welcome, happy to help. Cheers!
